# Using relative path for TNS_ADMIN in web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, odp.net

I'm trying to configure my web application to use `tnsnames.ora` file located in `bin` folder of application, but it only works when I specify full path to the `bin` folder.

Is there any way to use relative path?

I've tried following variants with no luck:

```
<setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="bin"/>
<setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="/bin"/>
<setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="~/bin"/>
<setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="\bin"/>
<setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="~\bin"/>
<setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="bin/"/>
<setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="bin\"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

TNS_ADMIN is also a supported environment variable, which means you could do this via code in your global.asax's Application_Start:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TNS_ADMIN", Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
```

That said, I wonder if you need to do this.  If you have a tnsnames file that's global, than you could just set the TNS_ADMIN as a system environment variable and then everything would use it.  But if these tns aliases are specific to your app, you could simply include them in the config itself:

```
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="Server1" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server1-scan.company.com)(PORT = 1526))
          (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME = server1.company.com)
          )
        )
      " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

I'm not saying there's anything wrong with what you're doing, but in general tnsnames is for centralizing some of the tns config, where you want to have a file that seems to be specific to your app.

Comment: Well, we have a number of projects in solution which require information about DB connection. The main goal was to share connection strings and TNS aliases across these projects so they could be easily changed for all applications. That's why I don't want to use the second option (dataSources in web.config files).
The first option is unacceptable because we have different applications hosted on one server.

Comment: I guess if you're trying to share over projects, why are you trying to make tns relative to a project?  Why not set tns_admin at the machine level and have just one tnsnames.ora on that machine.  If you want to share connection strings you could put them in the machine level machine.config or web.config (same goes for the tnsaliases should you not want to use tns_admin.  Again, no right answer here..  Just helping explorer your options.

Comment: finally we had to place tnsnames.ora in the client's network\admin folder on each server. Product manager from Oracle agreed with the problem and created a bug (https://community.oracle.com/message/13575256#13575256).

Comment: Interesting that they classified it as a bug.  "Relative" is somewhat murky with a web app.  In a windows app "relative" is to the exe.  But in a web app, the exe is the iis process, so you're looking for relative to the config file.